# Resolving merge conflict in git pull?

Tags: git, github, git-pull

I need help in  resolving merge conflict in git pull from GitHub, I did following 
on my current branch, I did the following
fa

1. `git pull --rebase master`
2. `git pull ssh:.....` (pulled changes from my review)
3. there was merge conflict in one file
4. removed all conflicts
5. `git add .`
6. when I tried to commit back using `git commit --amend` I got error

> "fatal: you are in the middle of merge -- cannot amend"

I want to amend same commit again without createating new commit ID. is there a way ?

Comment: `I want to amend same commit again without createating new commit ID` ... you can't do that.  Regading your immediate error, did you run `git status` after resolving the merge conflicts?  If you saw a message which showed that there are still some conflicts present, then this would prevent you from committing.

Comment: While merging you don't create new commits aside from the merge commit. When `git status` shows all conflicts are fixed, you run `git merge --continue`

Comment: I see message "All conflicts fixed but you are stil merging " use git commit to conclude merge"

Comment: Thanks for Help Folks ,git merge --continue worked for me.

Comment: Note that `git merge --continue` simply runs `git commit` ["under the hood"](https://www.quora.com/What-does-under-the-hood-mean-in-programming). It's nice that the Git folks added this as an option in Git version 2.12.0. If your Git is *older* than that, though, you *must* use `git commit` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that your history looks like:

```
B    C1   C2
o----o----o master
      \
       o feature
       F
```

You can either rebase the changes from `feature` onto the branch you are pulling them in to (`master`) to make it a "fast-forward merge", creating linear history:

```
B    C1   C2   F
o----o----o----o master, feature
```

Or, in the stage you describe you can run `git commit` (without `--amend`) to proceed to create a commit recording the result of the merge:

```
B    C1   C2   M
o----o----o----o master
      \       /
        --o--  feature
          F
```

If you prefer to have an explicit merge commit to denote that you merged a feature branch you can rebase and then merge using the `--no-ff` flag, creating something like this:

```
B    C1   C2        M
o----o----o---------o master
           \       /
             --o--  feature
               F
```

Which variant you pick is up to you to decide; all three are valid. I typically prefer to rebase feature branches, so as to avoid having to solve merge conflicts in a separate commit (the merge commit). Keeping the history linear (no merges) or not is a matter of workflow and taste.